# How can I get the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format in (OS X) bash?

Tags: macos, bash

Writing a shell script and I want to do something like this:

```
cp myfile.ext myfile.2011-06-10.ext
```

where 2011-06-10 is the current date.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
cp myfile.ext myfile.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.ext
```

or use shorthand format

```
date +%F
```

Comment: You can also use `date +%F` as a shorthand

Comment: @YzmirRamirez `%F` works for GNU date, but it is not POSIX compliant (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html). I recommend standard interfaces when they are not too budensome.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
 cp myfile.ext myfile.`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.ext
```

and for a proper solution, decompose the name first into basename and extension, assign the date and then reassemble for final targetname.

The key is that

```
 date +FORMAT
```

allows for very rich format strings. See `date --help` or the rather fine manual.

Answer (score 4):

The [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) for the `date` utility contains examples of how to output the date in various ways.

Answer (score 3):

```
cp myfile.ext myfile.$(date +%F).ext
```

Comment: %F is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html).Are you sure it works on OS X?

Comment: @Nemo, confirmed in macOS High Sierra